# installr:install.pandoc() appears broken

Tags: r, pandoc

I recently noticed that the `install.pandoc` function in the `installr` package appears to be broken.

I get the following error message:

```
trying URL 'https://github.com/'    
Content type 'text/html; charset=utf-8' length unknown    
downloaded 78 KB

github.com is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running. Check your computer's system information and then contact the software publisher.
```

It looks like the function is not finding the appropriate file from GitHub. I have submitted a pull request to the `installr` package on GitHub which corrects this error.

Comment: Can you make this into a question?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the function that should install Pandoc correctly and that was submitted as a pull request. In case you run into this error before it is fixed.

```
library(installr)
FixedInstall.Pandoc <- function (URL = "https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/releases", use_regex = TRUE, 
          to_restart, ...) 
{
  URL <- "https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/releases"
  page_with_download_url <- URL
  if (!use_regex) 
    warning("use_regex is no longer supported, you can stop using it from now on...")
  page <- readLines(page_with_download_url, warn = FALSE)
  sysArch <- Sys.getenv("R_ARCH") 
  sysArch <-  gsub("/ |/x", "", sysArch)
  pat <- paste0("jgm/pandoc/releases/download/[0-9.]+/pandoc-[0-9.-]+-windows",".*", sysArch, ".*", ".msi")
  target_line <- grep("windows", page, value = TRUE)
  m <- regexpr(pat, target_line)
  URL <- regmatches(target_line, m)
  URL <- head(URL, 1)
  URL <- paste("https://github.com/", URL, sep = "")
  installed <- install.URL(URL, ...)
  if (!installed) 
    return(invisible(FALSE))
  if (missing(to_restart)) {
    if (is.windows()) {
      you_should_restart <- "You should restart your computer\n in order for pandoc to work properly"
      winDialog(type = "ok", message = you_should_restart)
      choices <- c("Yes", "No")
      question <- "Do you want to restart your computer now?"
      the_answer <- menu(choices, graphics = "TRUE", title = question)
      to_restart <- the_answer == 1L
    }
    else {
      to_restart <- FALSE
    }
  }
  if (to_restart) 
    os.restart()
}
```